# Issues With Child Elements of the DOM Respecting Parent Styling

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm having is regarding segmenting with divs in HTML. I have a parent div that has a border set for it with child divs placed within it (I'm creating a scoreboard for baseball as a test for nesting and layouts). However, despite the parent div containing the border, the children of the div elements are breaking out of the border as well as the divs themselves. Any ideas? Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BaseballScoreboard.css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:green;">

        <div class="scoreboard">

            <div>
                <p id="atbat" class="text1">AT BAT</p>
                <p id="atbatnum" class="num">12</p>
                <p id="ball" class="text1">BALL</p>
                <p id="ballnum" class="num">3</p>
                <p id="strike" class="text1">STRIKE</p>
                <p id="strikenum" class="num">2</p>
                <p id="out" class="text1">OUT</p>
                <p id="outnum" class="num">0</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p id="inning" class="text2">INNING</p>
                <p id="runs" class="text2">RUNS</p>
                <p id="hits" class="text2">HITS</p>
                <p id="errs" class="text2">ERRS</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p id="visitor" class="text1">VISITOR</p>
                <p id="home" class="text1">HOME</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

...and here's the CSS:

```
.scoreboard{
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.text1{
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.text2{
    font-size: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.num{
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;

}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: In this case, you need to clear your floats. I would recommend looking into using grid or flexbox for this instead.

Comment: I thought it was the floats after a bit of experimentation.